# How can I initialize a state like, $|00\rangle$ or $|01\rangle$ or $|10\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$ in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state

Many thanks in advance for your help.
I am a beginner in Qiskit. I want to implement a circuit that uses the position of an element/item, of the form (x,y) and I would like to represent it as a state $|\phi\rangle = |xy\rangle$.
How can I initialize a state like, $|00\rangle$ or $|01\rangle$ or $|10\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$? Or how could I apply the tensor product to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is Qiskit code you wanted:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer, IBMQ, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

q = QuantumRegister(2)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)

#state |00>
circ00 = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
circ00.draw()
#do nothing, both qubits are already in state |0>

#state |01>
circ01 = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
circ01.x(q[1])
circ01.draw()

#state |10>
circ10 = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
circ10.x(q[0])
circ10.draw()

#state |11>
circ11 = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
circ11.x(q[0])
circ11.x(q[1])
circ11.draw()
```

State you want to prepare are so-called basis states in computational basis. You can easily prepare them with $X$ gate (i.e. equivalent of NOT in classical computation).
Initially, qubits are in state $|0\rangle$. If you want to change one of them to state $|1\rangle$, simply put on that qubit the $X$ gate.

Please run the code *per partes* to see how circuits differ for each of the basis states.

In Qiskit, you can also use function `initialize`. It uses vector representation of states, which are in your case:

- $|00\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^T$
- $|01\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^T$
- $|10\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^T$
- $|11\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^T$

So, the Qiskit code is following

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer, IBMQ, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, execute
import numpy as np

import numpy as np

q = QuantumRegister(2)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)
circ = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

#state = np.array([1,0,0,0]) #00
#state = np.array([0,1,0,0]) #01
#state = np.array([0,0,1,0]) #10
state = np.array([0,0,0,1]) #11

circ.initialize(state)
circ.measure(q,c)

processor = Aer.backends(name='qasm_simulator')[0] #simulator
res = execute(circ, processor, shots = 1).result().get_counts(circ)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the [Qiskit's textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html). It go through some introduction materials to quantum computing and while teaching you how to use qiskit along the way. I think it will worth your time.

In any case, to create the state you interested, you can use the following operations:

1. $ (I\otimes I) |00\rangle = |00\rangle$

```
        ┌───┐
q_0: |0>┤ I ├
        ├───┤
q_1: |0>┤ I ├
        └───┘
```

2. $(I\otimes X) |00\rangle = |01\rangle$

```
        ┌───┐
q_0: |0>┤ I ├
        ├───┤
q_1: |0>┤ X ├
        └───┘
```

3. $(X\otimes I) |00\rangle = |10\rangle$

```
        ┌───┐
q_0: |0>┤ X ├
        ├───┤
q_1: |0>┤ I ├
        └───┘
```

4. $(X\otimes X) |00\rangle = |11\rangle $

```
        ┌───┐
q_0: |0>┤ X ├
        ├───┤
q_1: |0>┤ X ├
        └───┘
```

Here $I$ is the identity gate (so it equivalent to you doing nothing) and $X$ is the [NOT gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.XGate.html).